# Query about initialization of objects created within a static method by the garbage collector

Tags: c#, static, garbage-collection

I have a question regarding the behavior of the garbage collector in C#.

I tried writing a simple code and testing it, but it returned null. I'm not sure about the details.

```
public static void Test()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add("test", "test");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test();
    while (true)
    {
       
    }
}
```

Comment: In my point of view, it should never end.

Comment: Of course. My program always runs, so it never ends... 
You may or may not be aware, The program is  an MES

Comment: So please ask your question. Or should we guess ? My guess would be u want to know when dic will be garbadge collected...

Comment: What exactly is the question? If `dic` will be collected? Yes. as a general rule objects are eligible for collection after they are no longer used, but the details may vary between GC implementations.

Comment: @JonasH It's *eligible* for collection, but if an infinite loop runs with no allocation and there is no memory pressure then a GC will never happen.

Comment: @Charlieface Absolutely, that's what I meant with implementation dependent. You could have a "Null GC" that just never collects anything, or one that is hyper aggressive at collecting. But yes, in practice, no collection will be done for such a trivial example.

Comment: @JonasH My program is in a constant build state. My question is that, After the Test method finishes execution, I'm curious if the objects created within the Test method become null when any action is performed.

Comment: Edit the question instead of posting comments. Objects do not become null, references to objects can be null. After the Test method completes the reference to the object will no longer exist at all. Since there are no longer any references for the object it becomes eligible for collection, and will be removed whenever the GC feels like doing a collection.